# Memory management for 2 "interconnected" C++ classes

Tags: c++, class

I have a class `Branch` and a class `Tree`. The declaration of the classes looks like:

```
class Branch{

private:

  map<string, double> properties;

  vector<Branch *> parent;
  vector<Branch *> children;

  int hierarchy;

  public: 
  ...

}

class Tree{

private:

  /* Tree is a vector of pointers to branches. */
  vector<Branch*> tree_branches;

  map<int,int> Hierarchy_distribution;

public:
...

}
```

1) If I understood well, the fact that the only attributes of `Tree` class are a `vector` and a `map`, makes it unnecessary to declare a destructor, a copy-assignement operator and  a copy constructor, because the memory is managed "inside" the vector and map templates.

2) I use this classes from a python code (I used cython to interface between C++ an python) and all the operations I make are performed through a tree object. I thought that because the branches I "use" are contained in a tree object (with a good memory management) I didn't need to declare a destructor, a copy constructor,and a copy assignment operator for the branch class. However I'm experiencing some problems and I think I have a memory leak.

Can someone confirm me if this could be causing a memory leak? If it is would stocking the `int hierarchy` inside a `vector<int>` avoid declaring a destructor and company?

**EDIT**

The branches who are stocked in the tree are created inside a method of the `Tree` class. It looks like:

```
Tree::addBranch(){
  Branch* branch2insert=new Branch();
  tree_branches.push_back(branch2insert);
}
```

As a local variable, is `branch2insert` destructed at the end of the scope? Do I need to write `delete branch2insert;`? Does someone have an idea of where do the `Branch` object at which I point to lives?

I still don't get why I need to ensure memory management when I never allocate ressources except inside the `Tree` class methods...

This whole thing is getting very messy in my head

**EDIT 2:EXAMPLE**

**branch.h**

```
#ifndef BRANCH_H_
#define BRANCH_H_

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Branch{

private:

      vector<Branch*> parent;
      vector<Branch*> children;

public:

      Branch();

      bool hasParent();
      bool hasParent(Branch* test);
      void addParent(Branch* p);
      void removeParent();
      Branch* getParent();

      bool hasChildren();
      bool hasChild(Branch*test);
      void addChild(Branch*ch);
      void removeChild(Branch*ch);
      void removeChildren();
      void removeDescendants();
      vector<Branch*> getBrothers();


};

#endif
```

**tree.h**

```
#ifndef TREE_H_
#define TREE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include"branch.h"

using namespace std;

class Tree{

private:

      vector<Branch*> tree_branches;

public:

      Tree();

      int getNumberOfBranches();

      Branch* getBranch(int branch_index); /* Returns branch at index. */
      int getIndex(Branch* branch); /* Returns the index of branch. */

      int getLastDescendantIndex(int ancestor_index); /* Returns index of the last descendant of branch at ancestor index. */
      int getParentIndex(int child_index); /* Returns index of the parent of branch at child_index. */
      vector<int> getBrothersIndex(int branch_index); /* Returns indexes of the brothers of branch at branch_index. */

      void addBranch(int parent_index); /* Adds branch without initializing its properties. */
      void removeBranch(int branch_index); /* Removes branch at branch_index and all its descendants. */

};

#endif
```

**branch.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#include "branch.h"

Branch::Branch():parent(vector<Branch*>()),children(vector<Branch*>())
        {
        }

bool Branch::hasParent(){
  if(parent.size()==0)
        return false;
    else
    return true;
}

bool Branch::hasParent(Branch* test){
  bool ret = false;
  for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=parent.begin();it!=parent.end();it++){//traversing parent vector
    if((*it)==test){//if test belong to parent vector
      ret = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

void Branch::addParent(Branch* mom){
  if(parent.size()==0){//if a branch hasn't a parent, multiple parents aren't allowed in a tree-network
    if(hasParent(mom)==false){//double checking if mom isn't already a parent
            parent.push_back(mom);//adding mom to parent vector
      }
    else{
      cout << "Branch::addParent Error: trying to add a parent twice.\n";
    }
  }
  else{
    cout << "Branch::addParent Error: trying to add a parent to a branch that already has one.\n";
  }
}

void Branch::removeParent(){
    if(this->hasParent()==true){//if this branch has a parent
      vector<Branch*>::iterator it=parent.begin();
      parent.erase(it);//erase it (it is the first and only element of the vector)

    }
    else{
      cout << "Removing the trunk.\n";
    }
}

Branch* Branch::getParent(){
  return parent[0];
}

bool Branch::hasChildren(){
  if(children.size()==0)
        return false;
    else
    return true;
}

bool Branch::hasChild(Branch* test){
  bool ret = false;
  for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=children.begin();it!=children.end();it++){
    if((*it)==test){
      ret = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

void Branch::addChild(Branch* ch){
  if(hasChild(ch)==false){
        children.push_back(ch);
        ch->addParent(this); // PARENTHOOD LINK ESTABLISHED IN ADD CHILD. ONLY
                         // NEEDED ONCE.
    }
  else{
        cout << "Branch::addChild Error: trying to add a child but the child has been already added.\n";
  }
}

void Branch::removeChild(Branch* ch){
  if(hasChild(ch)==true){
        for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=children.begin();it!=children.end();it++){
            if((*it)==ch){
                children.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  else{
      cout << "Branch::removeChild Error: trying to remove a child that doesn't exist.\n";
  }
}

void Branch::removeChildren(){
  if(this->hasChildren()==true){
    children.erase(children.begin(),children.end());
  }
  else{
    cout << "Branch::removeChildren Error: trying to remove all the children of a branch but tha branch hasn't any.\n";
  }
}

void Branch::removeDescendants(){
    if (this!=NULL){
      if(this->hasChildren()==true){
        for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=children.begin();it!=children.end();it++){
          (*it)->removeDescendants();
        }
      removeChildren();
      }
      for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=children.begin();it!=children.end();it++){
        (*it)->removeParent();
      }
    }
}

vector<Branch*> Branch::getBrothers(){
  vector<Branch*> brothers;
  vector<Branch*> potential_brothers;
  if (parent.size()!=0){
    potential_brothers=parent[0]->children;
    for (vector<Branch*>::iterator it=potential_brothers.begin();it!=potential_brothers.end();it++){
      if ((*it)!=this){
        brothers.push_back((*it));
      }
    }
  }
  return brothers;
}
```

**tree.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#include "tree.h"
Tree::Tree():tree_branches(vector<Branch*>()){
    Branch* trunk=new Branch();
    tree_branches.push_back(trunk);
}

int Tree::getNumberOfBranches(){
    int number_of_branches=tree_branches.size(); //retrieving size of vector
    return number_of_branches;
}

Branch* Tree::getBranch(int index){

      unsigned int u_index=index;
      return tree_branches.at(u_index); // returning branch at index of the tree vector

}


int Tree::getIndex(Branch* branch){
    int index=0;
    for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=tree_branches.begin();it!=tree_branches.end();it++){
      if((*it)==branch){
        return index;
      }
      index++;
    }
    cout << "Tree::getIndex Error: trying to get the index of a branch we can't find. Returning 0.\n";
    return 0;
}


int Tree::getLastDescendantIndex(int ancestor_index){

      if(tree_branches.at(ancestor_index)->hasChildren()==false){// if it is a leaf
        return ancestor_index;
      }

      if(ancestor_index==0){// if it is the trunk
        int N=tree_branches.size();
        int last_descendant_index=N-1;
        return last_descendant_index;
      }

      vector<int> brothers_indexes=Tree::getBrothersIndex(ancestor_index);

      for(vector<int>::iterator it=brothers_indexes.begin();it!=brothers_indexes.end();it++){

        int brother_index=(*it);
        if(brother_index>ancestor_index){

          int last_descendant_index=brother_index-1;
          cout << "The last descendant of" << ancestor_index << " is "<<last_descendant_index<<"\n";
          return last_descendant_index;

        }
      }
      int parent_index=Tree::getParentIndex(ancestor_index);
      Tree::getLastDescendantIndex(parent_index);
}

int Tree::getParentIndex(int child_index){

      if(child_index==0){ //if considered branch is the trunk
        cout << "Tree::getParentIndex: the trunk hasn't a parent. Returning -1.\n";
        return -1;
      }

      unsigned int u_child_index=child_index;
      Branch* parent=tree_branches.at(u_child_index)->getParent(); //retrieving the parent of the considered branch
      int parent_index=Tree::getIndex(parent);
      return parent_index; //returning parent index
}


vector<int> Tree::getBrothersIndex(int branch_index){
    vector<int> brothers_index;

    Branch* this_branch=Tree::getBranch(branch_index);//retrieving the branch from the index
    vector<Branch*> brothers=this_branch->getBrothers();//retrieving branch's brothers

    for(vector<Branch*>::iterator it=brothers.begin();it!=brothers.end();it++){ //traversing a vector containing the brothers of the consideered branch
      int this_index=Tree::getIndex(*it); //retrieving index of a brother
      brothers_index.push_back(this_index); //stocking the index in a vector
    }

    return brothers_index; //returning the vector containing the index of all brothers
  }


void Tree::addBranch(int parent_index){

      unsigned int u_parent_index=parent_index;
      Branch* mom=tree_branches.at(u_parent_index);//getting futur parent
      Branch* branch2insert=new Branch();//creation of branch to insert
      mom->addChild(branch2insert);//setting family relationship

      vector<Branch*>::iterator begin=tree_branches.begin();//creating iterators to manipulate vector elements
      unsigned int inserting_position=u_parent_index+1;//initializing inserting_position
      tree_branches.insert(begin+inserting_position,branch2insert);//inserting new branch

}


void Tree::removeBranch(int branch_index){

      int N=tree_branches.size();

      unsigned int u_branch_index=branch_index;
      Branch* branch2remove=tree_branches.at(u_branch_index);
      branch2remove->removeParent(); //removing parenthood link, if branch2remove is the trunk nothing will be done

      if(branch_index!=0){//removing childhood link between parent and branch_index
        Branch* branch2removeParent=branch2remove->getParent();
        branch2removeParent->removeChild(branch2remove);
      }

      int last_descendant_index=Tree::getLastDescendantIndex(branch_index);
      cout<<"The branch to remove is "<<branch_index<<", its last descendant index is "<<last_descendant_index<<", the size of the tree is "<<N<<".\n";

      branch2remove->removeDescendants();//removing family links for all descendents

      if(last_descendant_index==N-1){
        vector<Branch*>::iterator begin=tree_branches.begin();
        tree_branches.erase(tree_branches.begin()+u_branch_index,tree_branches.end());
      }

      else{
        vector<Branch*>::iterator begin=tree_branches.begin();
        unsigned int u_last_descendant_index=last_descendant_index;
        tree_branches.erase(tree_branches.begin()+u_branch_index,tree_branches.begin()+u_last_descendant_index+1);//removing the considered branch and its descendents from the tree vector
      }
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "tree.h"



using namespace std;

int main(){

  Tree tree;
  tree=Tree();

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    int N=tree.getNumberOfBranches();
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
      tree.addBranch(j);
      tree.addBranch(j);
    }
  }

  tree.removeBranch(21);
  tree.removeBranch(30);
  tree.removeBranch(50);

  return 0;
}
```

to compile:

g++ -Wall -pedantic -c

Comment: `vector<Branch *>` will correctly manage the `Branch *` that it holds, but it will not manage the `Branch`es that are pointed to by these pointers. Whoever created the `Branch`es that the pointers are pointing at is responsible for getting rid of them, not the vector. You could use `vector<Branch>` instead to make the vector responsible for the Branches.

Comment: Using `vector` doesn't magically absolve you from managing memory. If any of the pointers in `parent`, `children` point to objects on the heap, you still need to free them in the end.

Comment: Please also show us your `Tree`/`Branch` initialisation code.

Comment: @BenSteffan I can't put the whole initialisation since it is too big. Now I don't have the time to work on a minimal example.

Comment: What class owns the `Branch` objects that you have all these pointers to? How does your code know when their lifetime ends? If the `Tree` owns its branches, then it will have to `delete` them.

Comment: The only things which I create in my code are pointers to Branches. These pointers to Branches are stocked in a Tree. When I kill/remove a Branch* from the `tree_branches` vector I erase the vector entry and I erase vectors parent and children. Is it then when I need to call the destructor?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Also, whenever I see somebody mentioning "maybe memory leak" I expect him mentioning valgrind in the next sentence.

Comment: @Yunnosch check the minimal example. Sadly this is as minimal as it can get in order to reproduce what is done in the real code.

Comment: Impressive, didn't expect it to be that large, but it still is better than without - I think.

Comment: Well, I found the source of a bug, there is a problem in the `Tree::getLastDescendantIndex` I wasn't `return`ing in all the possible cases. Besides that I'm still concerned about the fact that it is memory leaking... Sometimes when I run my code in python, it stops running and python throws an error which when googled it is said to be caused by a memory leak...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) If I understood well, the fact that the only attributes of Tree class are a vector and a map, makes it unnecessary to declare a destructor, a copy-assignement operator and a copy constructor, because the memory is managed "inside" the vector and map templates.

You are wrong here, as the memory which is managed *inside* the vector is **only the storage for the addresses of branches**(`Branch *`). When you insert some branch you  call something like `tree_branches.push_back(new Branch)`, don't you? Thus, you will need to call the corresponding `delete` somehow, otherwise the default destructor of the tree won't take care of calling the destructors of the `Branch`es.

A quick fix for your code could be switching from `Branch *` to `shared_ptr<Branch>`. In such way, when the `tree_branches` vector is destroyed,  the `shared_ptr`'s will also be destroyed and when the latest `shared_ptr` to any `Branch`is destroyed, also the pointed `Branch` will be.

> would stocking the int hierarchy inside a vector avoid declaring a destructor and company?

It would change jack squat, as the `Branch`es default destructors still would not be called, and so the destructors of the `Branch`es members would never be called.

Comment: Thanks Davide, I find your answer quite clear. I do use `push_back(new Branch())` or `insert`. I will try the shared pointer and tell you.  Do I still need to declare a destructor for the `Tree` class? Would you also change `Branch*` to `shared_ptr<Branch>` inside the branch class (I mean for vector<Branch*> children)?

Comment: @bengo If you use `shared_ptr<Branch>` you don't need your own destructor. The default destructor of the container will destroy the shared pointers, and if you correctly allocate the object (use `make_shared`!) then the object will be destroyed when its last shared pointer is destroyed.

Comment: Care should be taken if switching to `shared_ptr` in this case. It's quite possible to create a circular reference causing nothing to be deleted. This would happen if you held both `parent`s and `children` by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SeanCline i don't think so. ultimately, the code seems to imply all the Branches are held by the Tree. then when the Tree vector member is destroyed, all the branches will be destroyed sooner(from the tree) or later (from another branch "outsurviving" them); This, provided a branch is not a parent or child of itself which should be checked and avoided in any meaningful application that comes to mind.

Comment: Indeed a branch can't be a parent or a child of itself. All the existing branches are contained inside the tree which can be traversed by iterating over the vector entries or by using the family relations between branches.

Comment: Do you think it is worthy to declare the destructor and etc? I wanted to avoid that because I'm a complete begginer in C++ (I'm using it in this project because it seemed interesting to use object oriented programming) and I found it complicated. But if I have to do it I can...

Comment: @bengo you don't need to if you use shared pointers, at the cost of a very small overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Finnally there isn't a memory leak. Thanks @Yunnosch for mentionning Valgrind, I wasn't aware this kind of tool existed.

@Davide I accepted your answer since it provided an alternative to what I've done, even if apparently there aren't problems with the management of the memory in my code.

The code I posted has a problem in function Tree::getLastDescendantIndex.

Comment: Your test will never experience the leaks ( which there are if using Branch* and never delete) simply beacuse 1) you use only one tree in your example 2) the scope of your tree matches the main() body, so that the leak actually exisit only on the very last instruction of your test.

Comment: what do you mean by "the leak exists only in the last instruction of your test"? Why using more trees would be a problem?